# Setting multiple values on one element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im using three multiple arrays in a project and I have to be able to cross reference them is there anyway I can set more than one bit of data to an element in the array?

For example I have an array called ballArray[] I use it like this:

```
function createBall(tempPosSize)
    {
        geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(tempPosSize,16,16),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff0000,reflectivity: 0.0});
        ball = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        ballArray[i] = ball;
    }
```

Is there a way I can set the `[I]` element like you would in JSON. So I would have `ballArray[i] = {Name : foobar, BallData: ball}`?

Comment: Like ballArray[i] = { data: ball, name: '1' }; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible exactly how you tried but there are some minor problems when setting the variables:

```
var ballArray = new Array();

function createBall(tempPosSize)
{
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(tempPosSize,16,16),
        material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff0000,reflectivity: 0.0});

    var ball = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    ballArray.push({Name: 'test', BallData: ball});
}
```

Comment: Ya it works. Just a slow afternoon i was calling `ballData` instead of `BallData`. thank you!